# Submit form with hidden field remotely

Tags: forms, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form based on bootstrap as follows, with a hidden field:

```
  <%= form_for @epochdate, {:class => "form-inline", :remote => true} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

    <%= f.text_field :currency, :class=> "input-small submittable", :placeholder=>"home fx", :value => @epochdates.currency %>

    <%= f.text_field :start_year, :class=> "input-small submittable", :placeholder=>"home fx", :value => @epochdates.start_year %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :scenario_id, @scenario.id, :class=> "submittable" %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn"  %>
  <% end %>
```

When I try the above form, nothing happens when I click submit (jquery ajax submissions are working on other forms in my app however)

I am not sure if I need to add a submittable class to the hidden field, and whether to place the :remote => true call within {} or outside. I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking but not sure what it is